# Sort NSArray by the results of the object's method

Tags: iphone, ios, sorting, nsarray, nsdate

So I have an NSArray with custom objects called Church. And in each church there is an array of mass times. So there is a method in church which calculates the closest mass to the user's current time.

```
-(NSDate *)closestTimeTo:(NSDate *)currentTime
```

I want to be able to sort the NSArray of Church by the results (which are NSDate) returned by that method for each object. Basically to get a sorted list of masses sorted by the closest time and also location.

I'm using categories and can't store the closest times as properties since its a core data object. I also don't think its a good idea to save those values to core data as these methods will be called constantly due to location services.

Any ideas on how I can sort such array using the result of its objects' method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following block. It would help directly(or at least with minor modifications).

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSDate *first = [(Church*)a closestTimeTo:currentTime];
    NSDate *second = [(Church*)b closestTimeTo:currentTime];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a new method in your class that takes another Church class and returns `NSOrderedSame`, `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedDescending`, depending on whether you want that object to be first or last. Use your `closestTimeTo` method to find that out. Then use `NSArray`'s `sortedArrayUsingSelector` call with your method.

Comment: sounds interesting i'll have to try these types out